# How to create a 2d array, the dimensions of which are specified by the user? (in C)

Tags: c, arrays, 2d

Here is my try. I am not totally sure about my manipulations with the pointer. Maybe this is why I am wrong, maybe there is some other case. I want to take the dimensions from the user and create a square matrix, make some manipulations with its elements, and display the original and results to the user. Last time I accomplished this by creating a 100x100 array, and specifying the end of each line, and end of lines by constants. Then I would print all the elements up to this constant. But it does not seem to be right to create a 100x100 array for 4x4 matrices. I could create a smaller array, but this does not seem to be the right solution to the problem. Is there a way in C to create a 2d array exactly the size specified by the users (it will be a square array). Thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

double * createMatrix(int dimentions);
void drawMatrix(double * matrix);

int main(void)
{
    int n, i, j;
    system("cls");
    system("color 70");
    system("pause");

    puts("Enter the matrix's dimension");
    scanf("%i", &n);
    double * pmatrix = createMatrix(n);

    for (i = 0; i < n; ++j)
        for (j = 0; j < n; ++j)
        {
            printf("A%i%i: ", i + 1, j + 1);
            scanf("%lf", pmatrix[i][j]);
            getchar();
        }

    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        putchar('\n');
        for (j = 0; j < n; ++j)
            printf(" %lf ", &pmatrix[i][j]);
    }

    system("color 08");
    return 0;
}

double * createMatrix(int n)
{
    const int N = n;
    const int N1 = N;
    double matrix[N][N];
    double * pmatrix = matrix;
    return pmatrix;
}
```

Comment: There is no way in C to create a standard two-dimensional array with runtime dimensions.  It has to be done dynamically.

Comment: @wallyk type arr[a][b] ; where a and b are local variables.

Comment: what problem are you having with the current code?

Comment: @2501:  That does not work in C.  Only C++ etc.

Comment: *That does not work in C. Only C++ etc. –  wallyk 1 min ago* It does work in C: http://ideone.com/0fH51G

Comment: scanf("%lf", pmatrix[i][j]); subscribed value is neither array nor pointer nor vector

Comment: @2501 Maybe format this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a matrix directly; you don't need a function for that. Replace the code

```
double * pmatrix = createMatrix(n);
```

by the regular way of declaring a 2-D array:

```
double matrix[n][n];
```

Comment: I was thinking about this, now I'll try

Comment: It worked, I thought about it from the very beginning, but I read somewhere that that is not possible in C, or my teacher told me that. Next time I am going to test new information.

Answer (score 0):

One more way of doing it using pointers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    double **pmatrix;
    int rowsize, colsize, i, j;

    printf("Enter the number of rows: ");
    scanf("%d",&rowsize);
    printf("Enter the number of columns: ");
    scanf("%d",&colsize);

    //Allocate memory for 2D array
    pmatrix = malloc(rowsize*sizeof(double*));
    for(i=0;i<rowsize;i++)
    {
        pmatrix[i] = malloc(colsize*sizeof(int));
    }

    //Accepting the values
    for(i=0;i<rowsize;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<colsize;j++)
        {
            printf("A %i %i: ", i + 1, j + 1);
            scanf("%lf",&pmatrix[i][j]);
        }
    }

    //Printing the values
    for(i=0;i<rowsize;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<colsize;j++)
        {
            printf("%lf\t",pmatrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    //Free the memory
    for(i=0;i<rowsize;i++)
        free(pmatrix[i]);
    free(pmatrix);

    return 0;
}
```